# Php. google news

Tags: php

Выдает ошибку при обращение к строке

```
$news = simplexml_load_file('https://news.google.com/news/feeds?hl=en&gl=ca&q='.$keys.'&um=1&ie=UTF-8&output=rss');
```

вот ошибка

PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file(https://news.google.com/news/feeds?hl=en&**amp;**gl=ca&**amp;**q=casino&amp;um=1&**amp;**ie=UTF-8&**amp;**output=rss) [<a href='function.simplexml-load-file'>function.simplexml-load-file</a>]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable

Скрипт работал нормально, но почему-то начал приписывать (**amp;**)

Как убрать это amp;?

Comment: Вам 503-я ошибка ни о чем не говорит?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы делаете парсер то лучше использовать **Simple HTML DOM**.
Пример [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872418/php-html-dom-to-parse-xml-second-result) (нашлось только это). А [тут подробнее](http://formata.net/it/primer-raboty-s-php-simple-html-dom-parser/) про весь Simple HTML DOM.

Answer (score 0):

я думаю это все прелести simplexml_load_file - вот этой функции, советую попробовать что-то иное.